# Algorithm in `oframed` environment

Tags: errors, algorithms, algorithm2e, framed

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength\FrameSep{5mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{oframed} Some text...

                \begin{center}
                \begin{algorithm}
                \DontPrintSemicolon
                \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
                \Input{The input to the algorithm}
                \Output{The output of the algorithm}
                \BlankLine
                \caption{This is what the algorithm does}
                \end{algorithm}
                \end{center}
           Some other text...
    \end{oframed}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way, we can remove the 'Undefined Control Sequence' error, while keeping the frame (because the algorithm is part of a big box containing other texts also, I don't want to remove the box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algorithm` is one type of `float` and `float` always having issue inside `\vbox` and `minipage`, you should use the package `float` and use the option `[H]` and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength\FrameSep{5mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{oframed} Some text...

                \begin{center}
                \begin{algorithm}[H]
                \DontPrintSemicolon
                \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
                \Input{$12$ numbered coins, $11$ of which have same weight}
                \Output{Number of the fake coin}
                \BlankLine
                \caption{Finding the fake coin in $3$ measurements}
                \end{algorithm}
                \end{center}
           Some other text...
    \end{oframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works.

Comment: @Martund Glad to hear....